# MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_APPROACHING not being triggered when using MediaRecorder's setMaxFileSize

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, android-mediarecorder

The `MediaRecorder` has an API that lets you automatically chunk the output stream into equally sized files.

For that you have to:

1. Call `setMaxFileSize` before calling `prepare` with the maximum size that you want each individual file to be set to
2. Subscribe to info notifications using `OnInfoListener` and call `setNextOutputFile` when `MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_APPROACHING` is reached.

The problem is that although doing everything specified by the documentation, `MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_APPROACHING` is never triggered and instead `MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_REACHED` is triggered later, after which the `MediaRecorder` no longer outputs data to any file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, unfortunately, is that Android's `MediaRecorder` API for `setMaxFileSize` not fully implemented by all the audio encoders (MPEG-4, AAC, AMR).

If we take a close look at their C++ implementations:

- [MPEG4Writer.cpp](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/MPEG4Writer.cpp)
- [AACWriter.cpp](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/AACWriter.cpp)
- [OggWriter.cpp](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/OggWriter.cpp)
- [MPEG2TSWriter.cpp](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/MPEG2TSWriter.cpp)
- [AMRWriter.cpp](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/AMRWriter.cpp)

We can see that only MPEG-4's implementation notifies the `MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_APPROACHING` event:

```
notify(MEDIA_RECORDER_EVENT_INFO, MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_APPROACHING, 0);
```